# Вопрос про DataTable

Tags: c#, sql

Сделал метод для выполнения любого sql запроса из базы данных, 1) подскажите, а вот DataTable в себя принимает результат выполнения запроса из базы,(то есть DataTable не затягивает в себя все данные и потом уже делает запрос на стороне клиента, или запрос происходит в базе и выдается только результат).

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connectionString = @"Data Source=VLADIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=northwind;Integrated Security=True";
            string qwery = "SELECT TOP 1000 [ProductID]\r\n      ,[ProductName]\r\n  FROM [northwind].[dbo].[Current Product List]";

            GetZapros2(connectionString,qwery);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void GetZapros2(string _connectionString, string qwery)
        {

            string connectionString = _connectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }

            var dt = new DataTable();

            //получаем результат запроса в DataTable...
            using (var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(qwery, connectionString))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }

            //далее работаем с DataTable...
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString() + "; ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

    }
```

2) Как  эффективно выловить возможные ошибки. Запрос например выдал ошибку,что я увижу в  DataTable?

Comment: А попробовать самостоятельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `ADO.NET`- это технология работы с данными автономно.
   Когда `DataAdapter` заканчивает наполнение `DataTable`, то он закрывает соединение и вы работаете с копией(вырезкой), которая никакое влияние не оказывает на исходные данные.
   Когда вы хотите пульнуть данные назад в базу, то отправляете ему свой `DataTable` и он шлет данные на сервер. И пуляет он не все данные, а только измененные, что бы уменьшить трафик.
2. Вы словите ошибку в моменте наполнения и DataTable останется пустым.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я из тех соображений спрашиваю, что  удобнее когда все выборки делаются в базе , а не в копии у клиента, и обратно к клиенту улетает уже результат выборки.